# How do I process an element before moving on to the next one in a for each loop?

Tags: javascript, prompt, bluebird

```
var prompt = ...
var connection = ...

prompt.start();

var property = {
  name: 'yesno',
  message: 'approve this screencast?',
  validator: /y[es]*|n[o]?/,
  warning: 'Must respond yes or no',
  default: 'no'
};

connection.queryAsync('SELECT * FROM screencasts WHERE approved = 0')
  .spread(function(screencasts) {
    screencasts.forEach(function(screencast) {
      console.log('Title: "' + screencast.title + '".');
      prompt.get(property, function(err, res) {
        console.log('Command-line input received:');
        console.log('  result: ' + res.yesno);
      });
    });
  });
```

**Aim:** To enumerate the `screencast`s and prompt the user to approve or deny them, interactively.

**Problem:** I think the problem is that, the loop does not block at all, resulting in the next element being processed too quickly:

[image]

How do I wait for the user to input a value before "processing" the next element in the sequence?

Comment: I did tag the question as [`prompt`](https://github.com/flatiron/prompt), but to be unequivocal, here is a link to the specific module I am using: https://github.com/flatiron/prompt

Answer (score 0):

Someone mentioned `mapSeries`, and that got me thinking about the [**example**](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird#what-are-promises-and-why-should-i-use-them) that shows how to **avoid** `mapSeries` and instead use bluebird's `map`.

What I ended up with is this:

```
var promise = ...   
var prompt = ...
var connection = ...

promise.promisifyAll(prompt);
...

connection.queryAsync('SELECT * FROM screencasts WHERE approved = 0')
  .spread(function(screencasts) {
    var current = promise.resolve();
    promise.map(screencasts, function(screencast) {
      current = current.then(function() {
        console.log('Title: "' + screencast.title + '".');
        return prompt.getAsync(property);
      }).then(function(res) {
        console.log(res);
      });
      return current;
    });
  });
```

It seems to work well. I am curious, though. Is `map` the most appropiate function for this?

Comment: No, using `Promise.map` is inappropriate here. You could have used the original `screencasts.forEach` with this approach as well. Instead, you should use `Promise.reduce`, so that you can avoid writing out this `current = current.then(…)` thing.

Comment: Can you please show me how, Bergi? Thank you for your comment, mate.